# i want to combine two 2d array into array with points

Tags: arrays, 2d

I want to combine two 2D arrays into one `Nx2` array.
For example `a=[1,2,3] b=[4,5,6]`, and I want to make `c=[(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]`.
i want to do it in python, but i don't know what command should i use. any hint?

Comment: a programming language would do that.

Comment: Any programming language would be OK to do `matrix transpose` operation. One example is ruby. Check http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose

Comment: i want to do it in python, i just don't know what exact command should i use

Answer (score 2):

you can do that in any language you want, the algorithm will likely be the same.  What you want to do is

- create matrix c
- read through each array
- grab the point at index i in each
- put a[i] into matrix row i column 0
- put b[i] into matrix row i column 1

here's some pseudo code to illustrate

```
int [][] c;

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    c[i][0] = a[i];
    c[i][1] = b[i]; 
}
```